# RIA .NET service installation error

Tags: .net, silverlight, service, ria

I am trying to install Microsoft .NET RIA services Preview (RiaServices.msi) on a machine running Windows 7 RC + Visual Studio 2008 SP1, and get the following error: "2908. Error while installing assembly System.Web.DomainServices.Tools.VisualStudio, version 1.0.0.0.."

Anybody else had this problem? What should I look at?

Answer (score 0):

There is a post [here](http://www.add-in-express.com/creating-addins-blog/2007/11/12/windows-installer-error-2908/) that may help.

You might also try starting the MSI on Win7 by opening a command prompt *as an admin*, then running the MSI from that command prompt.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you very much for your guidance. I tried some registry hacking that was mentioned in the article, but it didn't work. Ended up reinstalling Silverlight 3 SDK, and RIA services installed without any problem.